# Python Doesn't Open File Even Though it Exists and Is in Correct Directory

Tags: python, file-io

I have a Python script that opens a data file, finds the relevant lines, and stores the results as a list of tuples. In the script there is a function **ValuesFromFile(year,month,day,soft_address)** that accepts the string values year, month, day, and an integer **soft_address** which is to be found in the line. The function is used over a range or dates to look through daily files, located in another directory. In detail, the function,

```
def ValuesFromFile(year,month,day,soft_address):
    """Given the year, month, day, find all the lines that contain the soft address
       and call GetValues() on the line to get the associated values over the hour.

       The function builds the filename, checks if it exists, then goes line-by-line
       finding the lines with the soft address.

       Return a list of tuples [(datetime, value)]"""

    filename = '../../BEMS/' + str(year) + str(month).zfill(2) + '/' + 'gd' + str(year) + str(month).zfill(2) + str(day).zfill(2) + '.txt'
    data_list = []
    print filename
    try:
        FileObject = open(filename,'r')

        for line in FileObject:
            check_line = line.rsplit()
            hour_check = 0 # Check the hour in case we are missing an hour
            if (str(soft_address) in check_line):
                temp_list = GetValues(line)
                for tuple_value in temp_list:
                    date = "%s-%s-%s %s:%s"%(str(year),str(month),str(day),str(tuple_value[0]),str(tuple_value[1]))
                    data_list.append((datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),tuple_value[2]))
        FileObject.close()
    except:
        data_list = MissingDay(str(year),str(month),str(day))
        print "Couldn't find file"

    finally:
        FileObject.close()
```

In the above function I create the filename string by concatenating the location of the file, `../../BEMS/str(year)+str(month).zfill(2)+'/'`, then the actual name of the file, `'gd' + str(year) + str(month).zfill(2) + str(day).zfill(2) + '.txt'`.  If the file is found, I check if the sting soft address is in the line, and then call another function. If the file is not found, it will print `"Couldn't find file."`

When I run the script over the time span of `2017-10-01` to `2017-10-15`, the file name is printed and then try-except-finally is executed. If the file is found and processed correctly, there is no output. If the file is not found the except is executed and the print statement printed. The results:

[image: Output from Python Script]

So the weird thing is that the script is able to find all of the other files. The file exists in the directory which is confirmed by checking:
[image: File Exists]. Also, we can see that all users have read permissions on the file from the previous screenshot. I tried doing a chmod on the file just to see and that didn't help, as expected.

To add to the weirdness, when I try and read the file from the interactive interpreter, *I am able* to open and read the file:

[image: Read of file through interactive interpreter]

Finally, I renamed the file to check.txt and put it in the same directory as the code, commented out the filename building, and replaced it with `filename = "check.txt"`, reran the script, and the file still wasn't found by the script. So this seems like it is specific to that file.

Comment: It may be helpful to add more diagnostic information to your `except` block. In particular, rather than just printing "Couldn't find file", print the exception object and the stack trace, so you can be completely sure exactly which line is causing the problem. If you're thinking "I'm pretty confident that my code only crashes with FileNotFoundError, so I don't need any of that extra stuff", then you should be doing `except FileNotFoundError:` instead of just `except:`. Then when a non-FileNotFoundError occurs once in a blue moon, the unhandled crash will give you all the information you need.

Comment: Side-note: You need to `open` your file on the line immediately *above* the the `try:` line (outside the block), not below it (inside the block). If opening fails, you'll try to call `close` on `FileObject`, which hasn't been assigned to yet. You should also get rid of the `close` at the bottom of your `try` block; the `close` in `finally` is going to be called no matter what, so in a success case, you end up closing it twice, once in the `try` block, then again in the `finally` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Kevin points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48176067/python-doesnt-open-file-even-though-it-exists-and-is-in-correct-directory#comment83331941_48176067), you shouldn't use bare `except` blocks that assume a particular error occurred. Given [the bug I pointed out in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48176067/python-doesnt-open-file-even-though-it-exists-and-is-in-correct-directory#comment83333024_48176067) (if `open` fails, the `finally` block will raise `UnboundLocalError` when it tries to call `FileObject.close()`), unless you're catching and suppressing the `UnboundLocalError`, the one thing that definitely *isn't* happening is a failure to open the file. More likely, your parsing is failing, and since you're treating all exceptions the same, you report a failure to parse as a failure to open the file.

To fix this, reorganize your code to avoid misreporting errors (and while you're at it, avoid `close`ing stuff that might not exist):

```
def ValuesFromFile(year,month,day,soft_address):
    """Given the year, month, day, find all the lines that contain the soft address
       and call GetValues() on the line to get the associated values over the hour.

       The function builds the filename, checks if it exists, then goes line-by-line
       finding the lines with the soft address.

       Return a list of tuples [(datetime, value)]"""

    # Simplify path construction just because
    filename = '../../BEMS/{y}{m:02d}/{y}{m:02d}{d:02d}.txt'.format(y=year, m=month, d=day)
    data_list = []    
    print filename
    try:
        FileObject = open(filename,'r')
    except EnvironmentError as e:
        print "Error opening file:", e
        return MissingDay(str(year),str(month),str(day))

    # No code should go here, as exceptions raised here don't benefit from with
    # statement guaranteed closure

    # with statement guarantees it's closed on block exit, whether or not exception occurs
    # Normally, you'd open it in the with statement too, but in this case,
    # you wanted to handle errors from open immediately, so we separate it a bit         
    with FileObject:
        for line in FileObject:
            check_line = line.rsplit()
            hour_check = 0 # Check the hour in case we are missing an hour
            if str(soft_address) in check_line:
                temp_list = GetValues(line)
                for tuple_value in temp_list:
                    date = "%s-%s-%s %s:%s"%(str(year),str(month),str(day),str(tuple_value[0]),str(tuple_value[1]))
                    data_list.append((datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),tuple_value[2]))

return data_list
```

This way you:

1. Only catch the error you intend to catch (`EnvironmentError`, which covers `IOError` and `OSError` on Py2, and aliases `OSError` from 3.3 onwards) from the one place you expect it (the `open` call)
2. Have an error message with more details, rather than blindly claiming it didn't find the file
3. All other exceptions from the rest of the code bubble uninterrupted, so you get a full stack trace and error message telling you what went wrong in the error cases you *didn't* expect

Comment: After adding the exceptions as suggested, I received an IndexError that was bubbling up as predicted by @ShadowRanger. This was due to a lack of data in the list that was being iterated over but when the exception was raised _Couldn't find File_ was printed to the terminal with no other information. This also explains why the interactive session could open the file; in the session I didn't split the lines into a list and iterate over the elements so no error was encountered.

Comment: One thing that I noticed in the `try-except` block above is that the exception should be `IOError`, right?

Comment: @MatthewRobinson: On Python 2, it should probably be `EnvironmentError` to cover all your bases (it's the parent of both `IOError` and `OSError`, and `open` can throw either); in Python 3.3, they normalized the error hierarchy, so `OSError` is the parent class of all the errors it could possibly throw (both `EnvironmentError` and `IOError` are just aliases for `OSError`). The problem was that all actual `IOError`s were an error in a system call, some of which got raised as `IOError`, some as `OSError` (or subclasses), and there was no real rhyme or reason to it.

Comment: I originally wrote `OSError` because I've typically been using Python 3, and that's the canonical exception there, but I've edited to make it `EnvironmentError` in the answer since your code is clearly for Python 2.